# Network / Social network analysis visualization tools?

Tags: graph-theory, big-list, cg.comp-geom, software, graph-drawing

I was using Jung ( http://jung.sourceforge.net/ ) to visualize page rank and found it a little slow and difficult to scale it beyond 100 nodes. I was wondering what other tools people use for network / social network analysis and visualization.

Comment: May I ask what this has to do with cs theory?

Comment: Visualising of large chunks of information is important for cs theroy, its also its own entire research field.

Answer (score 6):

[FLARE](http://flare.prefuse.org/) produces rather beautiful graphs and visualisations, and in fact I have used it for just this purpose with a small private social network. In particular you may want to look at "layouts" in the [demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo) as it gives an excellent demonstration of transforming between different ways of drawing the graph.

Answer (score 5):

Check [this link](http://networkviz.sourceforge.net/)
 for pointers to several network analysis and visualization tools. They include:

[GINY: Graph INterface librarY](http://csbi.sourceforge.net/)

[TouchGraph](http://www.touchgraph.com/index.html)

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/)

[GraphOpt](http://www.schmuhl.org/graphopt/)

[GVF/Royere](http://gvf.sourceforge.net/)

[Hypergraph](http://hypergraph.sourceforge.net/)

Also, check 
[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)
Graph Visualization Software from AT&T Labs and 
[Cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/)
: An Open Source Platform for Complex-Network Analysis and Visualization. Cytoscape is  one of the best tools and it is backed by a consortium of corporations and academic institutions.

Comment: do you have any recommendations as to which of these are better for different applications, or even some of the advantages/disadvantages of them?

Comment: I would recommend  Cytoscape for molecular and systems biology research. However, it can be used for general network analysis and visualization.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [UBIGRAPH](http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Demos/index.html). It is just amazing.

Comment: Amazing and easy to get something up and running fast.

Comment: That look seems to go to something unrelated now...

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Java version of Flare called [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) and I have been quite happy with it.
The "Physics-based force-directed graph layout algorithm" is quite fine.

In my research I did not find any useful tools of the published large graph visualizations (http://blog.vrist.dk/2010/04/15/reading-up-on-dynamic-graph-layout/)

I have a couple of videos of the toolkit in action here: http://blobvis.appspot.com/screenshots

Answer (score 2):

I've been *toying* with a combination of [R](http://www.r-project.org/), to do the analysis and some visualisation,
and [gephi](http://gephi.org/), for visualisation. R seems very powerful, with the right abstractions for doing statistical manipulations. It has three packages (at least) for doing social network analysis, `sna`, `igraph`, and `network`. Gephi has a nice feature for drawing dynamic social networks, but I haven't fully explored its capabilities yet.

Answer (score 1):

I started to use gephi which seems to be pretty nice.