# Software for Graph Analysis

Tags: graph-theory, software

I have some graph-data which I would like to analyze. If the software could automatically determine some characteristics (Is the graph planar, clique number or any other graph property) it would be great, but if I could move the vertexes per drag and drop it would be good enough.

I know that I can visualize graphs with Graphviz, but I can't interact with the graph.

Comment: See: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2257/network-social-network-analysis-visualization-tools

Comment: close as duplicate ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of 2257! I would like to initialize a graph with a text-file, but then I want to be able to move the verticles per drag and drop (almost like http://www.diagram.ly/ supports it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SAGE supports [interactive graph drawing](http://www.sagenb.org/home/pub/2351/). You can easily create customized software for your own use.

1. [Graph editor](http://www.radokirov.com/js-graph-editor/)

Comment: The only function of sage, which is almost like drag and drop, is "@interact
def f(r=(2..4), h=(1..8)):
    g = graphs.BalancedTree(r,h)
    g.show(graph_border=True)". But I would like to be able to move the verticles. This seems to be impossible with SAGE. Nevertheless, SAGE is a great piece of software.

Comment: It is possible to move vertices and also add, delete vertices. Check out the examples. Try `graph_editor(g)`.

Comment: Thanks MachineCharmer, thats exactly what I've searched for.

Comment: The links appear to be dead now. Any updates still available?

Answer (score 4):

The [Tulip software](http://tulip.labri.fr), developed by the Graph visualization team of my lab, has such a feature. It allows you to drag and drop vertices, color vertices/edges, can check for connectivity, acyclicity, planarity, etc. and implements several nice graph drawing algorithms.

It is written in C++ and has a very nice plugin system which allows you to write your own pieces according to your needs. There is a documentation online, but if you need any help please feel free to ask.

Comment: Looks good! +1 for plug-in support.